# if statement TCL

Tags: if-statement, tcl

```
proc test {} {

set infile [open "infile" r]
set linecount 0

while {[gets $infile line] > 0 {
    incr linecount

    set price [split $line ","]


    if {[reqexp  "Game" $price]} {

       set token [lindex $price end-3]
       set token1 [lindex $price end-2]

    } else {
       if {2 < $linecount < 4} {
       set token [lindex $price end-3]
       set token1 [lindex $price end-2]

       puts "$game"

}
}
}
close $infile

}
```

I have input file with many lines: I want to be able to puts line 2 to 4 but the if statement I put (if { 0 < $linecount < 2} , does not seem to be working . Do you know how I can ask the script to output for certain lines?

```
Game a b c
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6
```

Comment: I have never seen this syntax: `if {2 < $linecount < 4} {` before.   What language does that come from?   It certainly will not work in Tcl.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Do you have any suggestion as how can I write it differently for TCL script? The script puts out the content I want correctly but just the linecount seems to be incorrect as you pointed out.

Comment: @jay That's what `&&` is for... `2 < $linecount && $linecount < 4`. See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm for details.

Comment: To pick the lines from 2 to 4 _inclusive_, the `<=` operator is used. Using `<` would only pick line three, which isn't what your text asked for…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most languages, but *not* like Python, the binary `<=` operator will not do what you seem to expect when used like that. It ends up working as if it was written `(2 <= $linecount) <= 4`, and as the inner term evaluates to either `0` (for false) or `1` (for true), the outer one is always true.

The simplest way to get what you want is to use the `tcl::mathop::<=` command, which *does* do what you want with three arguments:

```
# rest of your code as it was...

if {[tcl::mathop::<= 2 $linecount 4]} {

# rest of your code as it was...
```

If you're stuck using an old version of Tcl that doesn't have that command (or if you prefer writing code in the following style), write this instead:

```
if {2 <= $linecount && $linecount <= 4} {
```

or (if you like more parentheses):

```
if {(2 <= $linecount) && ($linecount <= 4)} {
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly now. I would like now to  make the 2 and 4 a var (ie: set i  ??), since I will have a few of " if {(2 <= $linecount) && ($linecount <= 4)} {" . So, if I have 100 lines in the input files, I like to set i at the start of the program so that I can make the "{($i+1 <= $linecount) && ($linecount <= $i+4)} {". Is it possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: @jay I'm not sure, but it seems to me like that might be a smarter way to go about this? It may be too broad for a single question, but you may try to explain the big picture by adding some information to your question without giving too much details, then if it looks like there could indeed be a better day to do it, we can request for more information.